# what if equals and hashcode compare different values in hashmap?

Tags: java, hashmap

If I have a employee class as key of hashMap and I overrride employee equals function using id field and hashcode function using name field. What will happen?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: If I am not wrong, a hashMap uses the hashcode to get the bucket and equals to get the object from bucket.. So it should still work fine...

Comment: @Codebender: No, because you could have 2 "equal" objects but with different hash codes, so you could even end up with duplicates in your hash table.

Comment: @sstan, if they ve different hashcode they ll go to different buckets... So how ll it affect???

Comment: @Codebender Lookups will fail as contains() will check in the wrong buckets.

Comment: I think lookup will first find the bucket using hashcode... and then perform euals only on the objects in the bucket... So it will match the object with both hashcode and equals matching...

Comment: David Wallace's answer is correct actually. I just can't shake the feeling that it's a dangerous practice. @OP: Any reason why you don't want to derive your hashcode from the `ID` field as well?

Comment: @Codebender Correct. So if hashcodes don't match two equal objects will go to two different buckets. This allows duplicate values and fails while doing lookups too.

Comment: Undefined behaviour is what will happen.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you have an Employee in your Map. Now suppose that Employee gets married and changes her last name. Now, the `hashCode` of that Employee changes. `map.get()` looks for that Employee in a different bin of the HashMap than the one it is located at (due to the hashCode change), and doesn't find it.

Conclusion - you should use the Employee ID for both `equals` and `hashCode`.

Note that the problem here arises from the fact that you chose a mutable field (assuming name is mutable) to compute your hashCode, not strictly from using different fields to calculate hashCode and equals.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the contract of `hashCode` says

> If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result.

So, provided you don't have any cases where

- two `Employee` objects have the same id, but different names, OR
- an `Employee` object changes its name,

then you'll be fine.

In fact, what you're proposing sounds perfectly reasonable, provided of course that the `id` values are unique, across all of the employees that you'll be storing in the map.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some scenarios, that might occur if you override hashcode using empName and equals using empId.

**Note: The below implementation of hashcode and equals method is done as per question's requirement**.

**Employee.java**

```
public class Employee {
    private String empId;
    private String empName;

    public Employee(String empId, String empName) {
        super();
        this.empId = empId;
        this.empName = empName;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {

        return empName.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {

        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        Employee employee = (Employee) obj;
        return this.empId.equals(employee.empId);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee [empId=" + empId + ", empName=" + empName + "]";
    }

}
```

**TestHashCode.java**

```
public class TestHashCode {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<Employee, String> map = new HashMap<Employee, String>();

        /**
         * Below two object are unequal by equals method and have same hash
         * code. Both employee1 & employee2 will be stored in same bucket
         * Corresponding to hash code in a linked list.
         */
        Employee employee1 = new Employee("123", "abc");
        Employee employee2 = new Employee("124", "abc");

        map.put(employee1, "abc");
        map.put(employee2, "xyz");
        // output:Collosionresult:abc,xyz
        System.out.println("Collosionresult:" + map.get(employee1) + ","
                + map.get(employee2));

        /**
         * Below two object are equal by equals method and have same hash code.
         * Value will be overridden. Meaning both employee3 & employee4 will get
         * the same value ie. the most recently updated value(world).
         */
        Employee employee3 = new Employee("hello", "pqr");
        Employee employee4 = new Employee("hello", "pqr");
        map.put(employee3, "hello");
        map.put(employee4, "world");
        //Output:OverriddenResult:world,world
        System.out.println("OverriddenResult:" + map.get(employee3) + ","
                + map.get(employee4));          

    }
```

**The general contract of hashCode is:**

> - Whenever it is invoked on the same object more than once during an    execution of a Java application, the hashCode method must
>     consistently return the same integer, provided no information used in 
>     equals comparisons on the object is modified. This integer need not
>     remain consistent from one execution of an application to another
>     execution of the same application.
> - If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then    calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must
>     produce    the same integer result.
> - It is not required that if two objects are unequal according to the    equals(java.lang.Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on
>     each of the two objects must produce distinct integer results.
>     However, the programmer should be aware that producing distinct
>     integer results for unequal objects may improve the performance of
>     hashtables.